# Unable to winscp png files

Tags: scp

I have a few PNG files that need to be `scp`'d to a Linux box. I'm using `winscp` and when I copy for some reason the number of bytes transferred is zero and in turn the file is empty..

What option needs to be changed in `winscp` to copy these PNG files?

Answer (score 3):

From the WinSCP documentation titled: [Transfer Modes](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/transfer_mode), I see there are 2, binary mode and text mode for transferring a file.

> ===== Server-side Text File Format =====
>
> There are two options how to support text mode transfers. The first option is that the client
> (WinSCP) knows directly the text file format used by the server and
> converts the file to the format before transfer. The second option is
> that there is some in advance agreed canonical format to which the
> client converts the file before transfer and from which the server
> converts it (if necessary) after transfer to its own format.
>
> The second option is more universal, but it is supported only by
> [[sftp|SFTP-4]] and newer and [[FTP]]((Actually with FTP, file is
> uploaded unmodified, anticipating the server to be able to convert it
> to its own format.)).
>
> The first option is used by WinSCP for [[SCP]] and SFTP-3 and older
> protocols. It this case the client (WinSCP) must directly know and
> support the server-side format. Generally there are plenty of text
> file formats, almost every platform has it own format. WinSCP supports
> two of the most used formats, Unix and Windows. You can select between
> them on //[[ui_login_environment#end-of-line_characters|Environment
> page]]// of Advanced Site Settings dialog. As most SSH servers are run
> on Unix system, generally you may leave the default Unix format.

So I believe you have automatic mode which should detect the png type by default. Otherwise, I suspect the issue may be either this article titled: [Topic "WinSCP FTPing ZERO byte files"](http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12622) or this article titled: [Why is my uploaded file 0 bytes?](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/139/Why+is+my+uploaded+file+0+bytes?#gs).